# Onscreen keyboard layout localization

Tags: localization

My product on Windows XP is beginnig the task of supporting on screen keyboard layouts for more than English.  Is there a way of presenting a keyboard in a specific language without having to invent the wheel - ie like knowing every dead key charater combination for every key for every language? Is their software out there that does this already?

Comment: The On-Screen keyboard that comes with Windows? Windows has a notion of keyboard layout, there should be API for accessing these data. (There are available several layouts for English, some other languages also have more than one.)

Comment: Isn't it a bad design decision to cover a task in an app while the OS already coovers exactly that task nicely? Sure there is an API for figuring out the keyboard layout etc. -- but isn't the onscreen keyboard of Windows' useful enough? What if there is some keyboard manufacturer delivering a totally strange keyboard, and that keyboard manufacturer provides his own onscreen keyboard, possibly replacing the XP one completely -- would you want to have to get active and support that exotic layout, too? Probably not?!?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this route, this might help:

[How to write an localized on-screen-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781440/how-to-write-an-localized-on-screen-keyboard)